# boot 22.04 from USB - black screen, hangs - FIXED

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04, live-usb, nomodeset

I've got a Dell with Intel processor and NVIDIA card and Windows 11 loaded. I'm trying to boot Ubuntu 22.04 from a USB.  When I hit Try or Install Ubuntu from the GRUB screen it brings up a black screen with a steady cursor in the upper left and hangs. I've tried the nomodeset and some of the other modeset options, but I get the same result. I've tried turning off Secure Boot, but that didn't help. I'm not able to get a terminal with any of the function keys.  Any other ideas on what I can try?

The fix to this problem was waiting for an updated ISO from Ubuntu. The computer now boots with no problems.

Comment: Did you verify the ISO prior to write to media?  Have you validated the write of ISO using another box?  Was the ISO an appropriate *architecture* for your intended machine?  Did you try removing `quiet splash` etc. from the kernel line so you can see more messages/clues for your *unspecified* 22.04 ISO?

Comment: Please tell us more about your computer: Which **model** of Dell is it? What graphics chip/card is it (brand name and model)? Some Dell computers need an **updated BIOS** in order to boot well from USB into Ubuntu.

Comment: The computer is a Dell Inspiron model# i7710-7952WHT-PUS

Comment: Processor: Intel 12th Gen Core i7 model# 1255U
Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce MX550
I did check for updates on the UEFI as part of my troubleshooting.
I did verify the ISO prior to write to media.  I have not validated the write using another box - I'll try that next.  The image I downloaded was the 64-bit PC desktop image.  I did remove quiet splash.

Comment: Please add details to your question, as that's what is answered.  Comments are from readers/mods/users of this site to the *Original Poster* and get removed once the question clarifies or provides details; commenting to yourself makes no sense? You are aware this is a Q&A site and not a forum.

Comment: I suspect that [at least part of] your problem is related to the nvidia graphics chip/card. Please try with the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`, and if that is successful, install Ubuntu, and use `nomodeset` also in the installed system. When booted into the installed system, install a proprietary nvidia driver to take full advantage of the graphics chip/card.